# How to add folder and subfolder to gitignore?

Tags: git, github

I have added the gitignore file but the /node_modules is still showing untracked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images. Copy and paste the text.

Comment: It's very hard to read the second screenshot (red on black, ugh). Your Notepad window is somewhat readable, and leads me to ask: are you saving the file in UTF-16 encoding, or UTF-8 encoding? Git cannot read UTF-16.